# Связи таблиц (Table Relations)

Tags: база-данных, relation, связи

Добрый день!
У меня вопрос для кого-то он может показаться глупым, но я до сих пор ни как не могу понять как работают связи (один ко многим, один к одному и тд).
У меня имеются 2 таблицы User и Rule. В таблице Rule хранятся права доступа для определенного пользователя, и у 1-го пользователя может быть только одно право, но у таблицы прав ведь могут быть множество пользователей.
Я считаю такую связь один к одному, правильно ли я считаю и можно по подробнее описать, что к чему?
Заранее благодарю, не судите строго!

Comment: Опишите структуру таблиц. Возможно, из-за того, что вы неправильно ее представляете, и появляется непонимание.

Comment: Здесь не имеется дело именно в текущих таблицах, а вообще как работают и как понимать связи.

Comment: Непонятно, почему вы считаете, что связь один-к-одному, если до этого сами же говорите, что у "таблицы прав могут быть множество пользователей". Почитайте, например, https://habrahabr.ru/post/193380/

Answer (score 0):

Вы допускаете одну маленькую ошибку в своих рассуждениях. Надо учитывать не реальное а возможное количество прав у пользователя. Допустим у зарегистрированного пользователя есть права создавать тему, отвечать на вопросы, комментировать сообщения других пользователей. Но вот кто-то предложил ему стать модератором, и сразу же может нарушиться целостность данных, так как предыдущие права у него не исчезли, а новые добавились. Поэтому нужна таблица, у которой будет структура id_user, id_rule. Добавляется новое правило, создается новая запись у которой тоже значение id_user, но другое id_rule. Если этого не предусмотреть то начнутся проблемы.